# What is wrong when I can not log into my session on Lubuntu?

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, login, vnc

**My question is a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) but I would like to keep it here because I did not find the other question when searching for a solution.**

---

I am not able to log into the Lubuntu session from the graphical login screen. I have login without password enabled and if I click on `login` it simply throws me back to this login page after 2 seconds of black screen.

---

I run a ZOTAC mini PC with Lubuntu 16 on it. I know it is EOL. It was running fine and I was accessing it via VNC from a Mac. It was running `Mediathekview` which is a graphical software to download TV content. It was connected to my Raspberry Pi's external HDD via samba so that it downloaded everything onto this HDD in the LAN.

My RPi crashed (sd card failure) and it seemed that the ZOTAC also had a crash because I could not close the filemanager. I never experienced this. I was thinking about the possibility that the download went on and my local HDD inside the ZOTAC got full. But this is not the case as `du` shows only 22GB.

---

Before I realized that I could not log in with a monitor and mouse attached I was just trying to log into VNC from a Mac and then on terminal trying to find out if VNC was maybe down. I was not able to `telnet 127.0.0.1 6000` and then attached a monitor to check what was going on.

I also tried to start `xserver` from the terminal when logged in via `SSH` and I am not sure if this maybe also messed up things. But I am pretty sure that the problem with the login was like this from the start.

---

I also tried to `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` and while I would have been expecting that this was already installed it was not and so I installed it (again). Now I have several options of graphical environments to log into: `LXDE`, `Lubuntu`, `Ubuntu` and `Openbox` but none of them work.

---

`top` looks like this. I think `java` indicates that `Mediathekview` is running and the `MongoDB` might be from a router management software. So there seem to be running things that only get started when I log into the system.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     ZEIT+ BEFEHL                                                                                                                             
   24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:00.01 kworker/3:0                                                                                                                        
  953 mongodb   20   0  388324  48624  18216 S   0,3  1,3   0:00.18 mongod                                                                                                                             
 1483 ntp       20   0  112096   5032   4412 S   0,3  0,1   0:00.02 ntpd                                                                                                                               
 1573 root      20   0 3545512  73280  19248 S   0,3  2,0   0:01.31 launcher                                                                                                                           
 1783 root      20   0 4631872 167540  22152 S   0,3  4,6   0:05.29 java                                                                                                                               
 2620 ben       20   0   43604   4052   3276 R   0,3  0,1   0:00.01 top                                                                                                                                
    1 root      20   0  120096   6308   4064 S   0,0  0,2   0:01.17 systemd                                                                                                                            
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                           
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                        
    4 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0                                                                                                                        
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                                                                       
    6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/u8:0                                                                                                                       
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.04 rcu_sched                                                                                                                          
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                                                                                                             
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                                                                        
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                                                                                                         
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 watchdog/1                                                                                                                         
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/1                                                                                                                        
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                        
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0                                                                                                                        
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H                                                                                                                       
   16 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 watchdog/2                                                                                                                         
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/2                                                                                                                        
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                        
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0                                                                                                                        
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H                                                                                                                       
   21 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 watchdog/3                                                                                                                         
   22 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/3                                                                                                                        
   23 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                                        
   25 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H                                                                                                                       
   26 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                                                                          
   27 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                                                              
   28 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 perf                                                                                                                               
   29 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                                                                                                         
   30 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 writeback
```

---

`.xsession-errors` is:

```
openConnection: connect: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: window-stack-bridge-main-Prozess (6441) wurde von HUP-Signal beendet
upstart: bamfdaemon-main-Prozess (6482) wurde von TERM-Signal beendet
upstart: lxsession-main-Prozess (6565) wurde von TERM-Signal beendet
upstart: Vom benachrichtigten D-Bus-Bus getrennt
Xsession: X session started for root at Di 3. Sep 16:49:50 CEST 2019
localuser:root being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

Comment: If this was a clean Lubuntu, you shouldn't see Ubuntu as a login option. There would be Openbox though. Losing `lubuntu-desktop` isn't a big deal. It can be removed if you uninstall certain packages specified by it.

Comment: Yes, openbox was also there. I am not sure how clean it was. :) However, I did not remove anything before the crash. Maybe I did a smaller update and did not yet restart.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: @karel Thanks a lot! Changing permissions for .Xauthority worked! But I must say I probably would not have found the other question based on the way it is stated.